# Viewing MS Office documents offline on an iPad 2 in an HTML5 site

Tags: ipad, html, ms-office, cache-manifest, offline-storage

I'm evaluating an HTML5 website that will allow the user to view MS Office documents (Word, Excel and PPTX), PDFs and possibly videos. All of this data should be accessible offline to the user on an iPad2.

After looking into concepts like cache manifest (and local storage), I understand that all this is possible, but what I am not clear about are the limitations of this approach. Is there a limit to the size of the offline storage? What happens if the user clears the iPad cache? (Does the stored data also get wiped out? Would he then have to download all those documents again?)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a limit to the size of the offline storage?

Yes.  In current browsers it's about 5Mb I believe.  In most browsers the user can increase the limit for particular websites, but it's not something you can control from inside your application.

> What happens if the user clears the iPad cache?

The their cached data should be cleared, but see also [Super Cookies](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/10/11/business/media/11privacy.html?src=me&ref=general).

> Does the stored data also get wiped out?

If the user is trying to delete their stored data then that's what I'd expect to happen.

> Would he then have to download all those documents again?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks - the storage limit is definitely to consider. I know offline storage can go up to 50MB, but what if the document/file size exceeds the limit? That's something for us to consider while designing the site.